# how to maintain version of web app

Tags: php, version-control, phpstorm

I am working on a PHP script where I release updates or fixes every few months and at present I am manually keeping record of version for example Product Name v1.7 or Product Name v2.2 and so on. I use PHPStorm for web development and wanted to know how do companies/people keep track of their version, do they also name and maintain it manually or is this an inbuilt feature in IDEs that can help keep track of this,

For example Wordpress, 3.7, 3.8 and many other open source/commercial products. I will really appreciate some feedback on this.

Comment: You use source control, e.g. git

Comment: NetBeans IDE nicely integrates with git, Subversion and Mercurial.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into your recommendations, do they help name and number the product as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using any version control like Git or SVN it's possible.

You can use a commit message including name and version number of product. Later you can list all commits with the commit message.

[image]

Browse Version history

[image]

Comment: thank you, I believe you are working on PHPStorm as well, what is the different between using the version control that comes with PHPStorm and for example Git and SVN, does the in built version control of PHPStorm offers numbering the version or it is better to use Git

Comment: I think you meant `Local History` option of PhpStorm. It is fully managed by PhpStorm and we cannot add message to that version history. It only shows date & time of change and which file is changed.

Comment: Thanks and yes I meant `Local History`, I will google to find steps on how to setup git with phpstorm, if you know of any good link please do share

Comment: First install Git http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Comment: Then you can create a local git repository by http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/setting-up-a-local-git-repository.html